# How do I redirect if user goes to a non public url on React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

ok so I have a template component called **Page**. If I go to different routes the same tamplate will be used with different information. This is what I have inside Page:

```
class Page extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.children);
    return (
      <div className="page">
        <Header></Header>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the Routes.js component:

```
<Route path="/" render={() => (
  <Page>
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/home' component={Home}></Route>
      <Route path='/users/new' component={RegistrationForm}></Route>
      <Route path='/users' component={Table}></Route>
    </Switch>
  </Page>
)}></Route>
```

However, when I go to localhost:3000/ it shows the template without anything. I wanted to redirect to /home if the user goes to /.

I tried placing

```
<Redirect>
```

like so:

```
<Route path='/' render={() => (
  <Fragment>
    <Redirect to='/home'></Redirect>
    <Page>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/home' component={Home}></Route>
        <Route path='/users/new' component={RegistrationForm}></Route>
        <Route path='/users' component={Table}></Route>
      </Switch>
    </Page>
  </Fragment>
)}></Route>
```

and now every page I go to gets redirect to /home. Does anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `from` and `exact` properties. In order to use both properties, such `Redirect` must be a child of a `Switch` component (look at the docs [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md#from-string)):

```
<Route path='/' render={() => (
  <Page>
    <Switch>
      <Redirect exact from='/' to='/home'></Redirect>
      <Route path='/home' component={Home}></Route>
      <Route path='/users/new' component={RegistrationForm}></Route>
      <Route path='/users' component={Table}></Route>
    </Switch>
  </Page>
)}></Route>
```

Comment: @JeffGoes please, if my answer worked for you, mark it as accepted (green checkmark ✓) and upvote it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Should be easy :)

You just need to add from prop to your `<Redirect>` and place it as the first route:

```
<Redirect from="/" to="/home" />
```

Comment: for some reason, even using that all of the routes are redirected to home... even if I try going to /users/new or /users